# Rstudio cannot step into the source code

Tags: r

I built my own R library mlib001, and did Build/Build source package, which produced tar file in that libs directory. Now I can reference that library from another main/test R script file with:

library(mlib001)

I also went to Tools in that main code screen, Install Packages, Install from Package archive, then brows to the tar file for that library mlib001, import - all gets loaded fine. I then run the main code with CTRL-ALT-R, it runs fine and invokes functions from mlib001 and all completes ok. But if I set breakpoint in the main code to step into the function from the library, once I do step  in I get the message that source code is not available: "Debug location is approximate because the source code is not available". How do I resolve this so I can step into the functions with the debugger? Thanks

Comment: The IDE tools in RStudio for debugging are for functions in your workspace (or for when actually developing and testing a package). If you want to step into a function that exists in a package, use `debug` or `debugonce`.

Comment: You should use RStudio to work in a project for package developing, then there are some tools specially designed for package build and test. You don't need to install from package archive or build tar manually. With package source file opened, you can set breakpoint inside the function, then run some code to call the function to invoke the debugger. Though sometimes RStudio still have problem to intercept a package function, you can always put `browser()` inside the code to debug.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - debugonce(mlib001:::function1) did work, after that I could step into the source code - but could not set additional debug breakpoints - except for the one put there when building mlib001 package. I will try browser() - have not tried that yet. Thanks

Comment: ... what are other tools - "...there are some tools specially designed for package build and test"?

Comment: A package build & load panel, some settings to update documentation in rebuild, etc. You can check RStudio documentation and `R Package` book by Hadley.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is applicable but I had similar problems because I copied some comments written elsewhere that included some scandinavian characters, like "ä".

Comment: Worked for me aswell